# Edit file using POST Method with API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

In API Platform documentation it says:

> Uploading files won't work in PUT or PATCH requests, you must use POST
> method to upload files.

But when i try to "force" method:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CompanyRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        "put" => ['method' => 'POST']
    ],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']]
)]
/**
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Company implements ImageInterface
```

I  got

> There is no builtin action for the item POST operation. You need to define the controller yourself

Any idea how to transform PUT to POST?

Answer (score 1):

POST operation are Collection operations, not item operations.

As per:
https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1663

Comment: I understand that... so how to edit an entity with file?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is (after following documentation https://api-platform.com/docs/core/file-upload/#uploading-to-an-existing-resource-with-its-fields)  to create a custom operation with POST method, and an empty controller:
entity/company.php

```
#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        "get" => ApiConstInterface::UNSECURE,
        'edit_file' => ApiConstInterface::SECURE_ADMIN_AND_OWNER
            + [
                'method' => 'POST',
                'controller' => EditCompany::class,
                'input_formats' => [
                    'multipart' => ['multipart/form-data'],
                ],
            ],
        "delete" => ApiConstInterface::SECURE_ADMIN_AND_OWNER,
    ],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']]
)]
/**
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Company implements ImageInterface
```

controller/EditCompany.php

```
#[AsController]
final class EditCompany extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(Company $data): Company
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```